# How do I test connection from Linux to Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: linux, sql-server

What's the simplest way to check connectivity from a Linux server (e.g. Ubuntu 18.04) to a remote Microsoft SQL Server 2017 instance?

Answer (score 18):

I think the simplest would be to try to telnet to MS SQL server from the command line:

```
$ telnet <server-name-or-ip> 1433
```

If your connection was successful the screen goes blank, otherwise you'll see something like *"Connecting to server-name-or-ip... Could not open connection to the host, on port 1433: Connect failed."*

Comment: so this is what a negative test?

Answer (score 11):

Another easy way would be to use `nc` (`netcat`) from the command line:

```sh
nc -zv YOUR_SERVER_NAME_OR_IP 1433
```

If a connection can be established, you should see an output like this:

```
Connection to YOUR_SQL_SERVER_NAME_OR_IP 1433 port [tcp/ms-sql-s] succeeded!
```

On failure, you get different error messages depending on the cause:

```
nc: getaddrinfo for host "NON_EXISTING_SQL_SERVER_NAME_OR_IP" port 1433: Name or service not known
```

or maybe...

```
nc: connect to YOUR_SQL_SERVER_NAME_OR_IP port 143 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out
```

From `nc` man page, `z` and `v` options are:

```
     -z      Specifies that nc should just scan for listening daemons, without sending any
             data to them.  It is an error to use this option in conjunction with the -l
             option.
     -v      Have nc give more verbose output.
```

Answer (score 9):

On the remote Microsoft SQL Server instance: make sure port TCP 1433 is open in the firewall.

On the Ubuntu Server instance install the mssql-tools as described here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/php/ubuntu

```
sudo su
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
exit
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

You can then run a test query - you'll be prompted for password:

```
[user@lnx01 ~ $] sqlcmd -S <remoteip> -U <user> -p -Q "SELECT @@VERSION"
Password: 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64) 
    Aug 22 2017 17:04:49 
    Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: )


(1 rows affected)
```

Comment: when creating/editing ~/.bash_profile the colours are removed from the shell (ie the user@host$ no longer has a colour). To avoid this you can send to ~/.profile instead.

Comment: This works ok, but mind the 2nd curl line, and check the provided link Chef Tony provides, so you download the correct version.

Comment: @ShervinRad mssql-tools seems to create a .bash_profile which appears to take over from .bashrc (at least in ubuntu distro) and means that nothing in .bashrc is run after that install. The most obvious symptom is the loss of colourisation in the prompt & the easy solution is as you suggest, put the exports in either .profile (or .bashrc)